# Why principal ideal should be commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

According to the definition of Principal Ideal it should be commutative. What if the ring is not commutative? Which means $ar\neq ra$ where $a\in I, r \in R$. Does it lead to a contradiction? Because I can't find a contradiction.

Comment: Your principal ideal does not come out of thin air, it's a particular subset of a ring. It is the ring which is either commutative or non-commutative. Therefore, the answer to your question is: if your ring is not commutative, you have the notion of left ideal, and the notion of right ideal, and these two different kind of objects are either principal or not

Comment: Well, a *subring* generated by one element should always be commutative. But a principal ideal, not necessary: e.g. the ring itself is a principal ideal, generated by $1$.

Comment: There's also the possibility you are talking about *principal ideal domain*: the *domain* part of this phrase implies the ring must be commutative. This generalizes to *principal (left / right) ideal rings*.

Comment: @Berci can you please explain, how a subring generated by one element has to be commutative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For noncommutative rings there are three different notions of ideal:

- *left ideal* (absorbs ambient multiplication from the left)
- *right ideal* (absorbs ambient multiplication from the right)
- *two-sided ideal* (absorbs ambient multiplication from both sides)

A left/right/two-sided ideal is principal if it is the smallest such ideal containing a given element of the ring (we say that element *generates* the ideal). One can show that $Ra$ and $aR$ are respectively the left and right ideals principally generated by an $a\in R$, where $Ra:=\{ra:r\in R\}$ and then similarly $aR:=\{ar:r\in R\}$. The two-sided principal ideal is more complicated to describe.

It seems you are asking if $aR=Ra$ always holds, even if $R$ is noncommutative. The answer is no it doesn't. In fact, none of the left, right and two-sided ideals principally generated by a single element are necessarily the same. Furthermore, the right ideal $aR$ generally fails to be a left ideal, and then symmetrically the left ideal $Ra$ may fail to be a right ideal, and further the two-sided ideal $(a)$ when considered as a left or right ideal may fail to be principal.

For examples of where this (pathological, one may at first feel) behavior, consider forming the noncommutative polynomial ring $k\langle a,b,\cdots\rangle$ out of some letters $a,b,\cdots$ and a nice ring $k$.